# Recycler View getItemViewType position issue

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Inside my adapter I use getItemViewType to decide based on the value wether to add a header and search indicator to the recyclerview.

> getItemViewType

```
private static final int TYPE_SEARCH = 0;
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 1;
private static final int TYPE_CELL = 2;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position == 0) {
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    }
    else if(position  == 1) {
        return TYPE_SEARCH;
    }
    else
        return TYPE_CELL;
}

 public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        final View convertView;
        switch (viewType) {
            case 0:
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_search_ind, parent, false);
                return new Adapter.ViewHolderSearch(convertView);
            case 1:
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_header, parent, false);
                return new Adapter.ViewHolderHeader(convertView);
            case 2:
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_normal_layout, parent, false);
               return new Adapter.ViewHolderFeed(convertView);
        }
        return null;
    }

public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   ....
}
```

So if the position is 0 it will inflate and return the header layout card, if position is 1 it will inflate and return the search layout card, else just return the "normal layout". What's happening now is, is seems like the header and search "headers" are using the two spaces where Dog10 and Dog9 should go. So now my recyclerview feed starts at Dog8. If I remove the two "headers", my recyclerview feed starts at Dog10. See image below to make sense of what I'm saying.

[Image of my app RecyclerView feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQISQ.jpg)

How do I get around this? Should I just add two dummy entries to the data that gets returned from mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can add dummy entries for the list. But make sure the onBindViewHolder() does not bind for position 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add two objects at index 0 and 1. and also better if you take property (instance variable) as a viewType so your adapter doesn't care about where you want to show header and search. and you add your dummy data with type Search and Header and give the default type as Item cell. hope It will clear all your doubts.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return data.get(position).getViewType();
}
```